# When to use php , asp and jsp while making an webapplication?

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, jsp, web

I recently went through an article which states the different combination to make an Web-Application , so I was wondering that when a developer should go for

1.php

2.asp

3.jsp/Servelets

anything on it would be appreciated

Comment: Always go with the language/technology in which you are comfortable.

Comment: @SainPradeep you mean it does not really matters what you use

Answer (score 1):

Developer should develop in which language he/she is comfortable.and client's requirement is also taken care of.

Open source web application should develop in PHP. Application meant to run in Windows server must develop in asp and in both the cases you can use java. Java is mostly use to develop desktop applications.

Comment: +1 for simple explanation. And if you are developing web application to host on webserver, java hosting cost is costly than php hosting.